# Why is the pdf output of my QGIS map different from the one I see in the Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I'm working on a map of migrant deaths and missings in and around the Medditerranean Sea. It includes a legend. When I work in the print composer mode, the legend seems to be looking fine. Here it is:

[image]

When I look at the pdf output of my map, however, it looks different:

[image]

The key issues here are the extra pink moon-like shape on the left, and the extra "1" at the bottom of the graduated circles.

I suppose this has something to do with the fact that I'm trying to hide part of the "wrong" graduated circles, which I'm overlapping with two images: correct version and a white image to cover the remaining bits. One can see the outlines of these images over here:

[image]

**Question**: why is the output of the legend in the pdf of the map different from the one in the print layout, and how can I make sure QGIS generates the correct output?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? I've experienced similar problems in a previous version of QGIS that disappeared in version 3.16.0.